# Use VS envirenment-variables as command-line args

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I can use envireonment-variables such as `$(TargetFileName)` in my pre- and post-build-events. What I want to do is apply those variables to the command-line args of an external program (in my case nunit). So whenever my app starts I want to start another one with the file-name of the first as arg.

Is this possible?

When debugging my project the nunit-windows appears but shows an error-message that the given assembly `$(OutDir)$(TargetFileName)$(TargetExt)` could not be found. I suppose that the variables are only available during build but not during run so it seems I have to hardcode the parameters to the command-line args. Is this true?